# In which work does Wolfgang Stegmuller criticize anti-inductivism and Karl Popper?

Tags: epistemology, reference-request, induction, popper

In the introductory note to the third edition of *Fact Fiction and Forecast*, Nelson Goodman writes that "Wolfgang Stegmuller has corrected the notion thnat 'anti-inductivists' of the school of Karl Popper escape the new riddle of induction". Goodman does not provide a reference for this claim. Which work(s) of Stegmuller is he referring to?

Comment: See [Wolfgang Stegmüller](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wolfgang_Stegm%C3%BCller#Selected_publications): I suppose that - unfortunately - most of them are not translated into English.,

Comment: I think you will find it in a paper by Wolfgang Stegmüller entitled "The Problem of Induction: Hume’s Challenge and the Contemporary Answers". The original in German is called "Das Problem der Induktion: Humes Herausforderung und moderne Antworten". It is included in his Collected Papers on Epistemology, Philosophy of Science and History of Philosophy, Chapter 4, pp. 68–136.

Comment: Stegmüller writes about this on pp. 90-94 of the English translation. The paradox specifically afflicts Popper's notion of corroboration, which amounts to inductive confirmation by another name:"*Popper has over dramatized his
opposition to Camap and that his disagreement with Camap has nothing to do with the antitheses 'deductivism - inductivism'... Goodman's paradox affects Popper's theory of corroboration (when
stated precisely) exactly as it does every other theory of confirmation... this simply amounts to transforming it into a jargon which sounds better to the deductivists.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let us give in full the citations of the primary article (original and its translation) Stegmüller discusses this issue:

Stegmüller, W. (1971). [Das Problem der Induktion: Humes Herausforderung und moderne Antworten](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-3-663-00199-7_2). In: Lenk, H. (eds) Neue Aspekte der Wissenschaftstheorie. Vieweg+Teubner Verlag, Wiesbaden.

Stegmüller, W. (1977). [The Problem of Induction: Hume’s Challenge and the Contemporary Answers](https://doi.org/10.1007/978-94-010-1132-7_4). In: Collected Papers on Epistemology, Philosophy of Science and History of Philosophy. Synthese Library, vol 91. Springer, Dordrecht.